# Using __init__.robot Suite Setup and Teardown to test multiple remote machines

Tags: robotframework

I've written an **__init__.robot** that expects a list of hosts.

On setup, it proceeds for each of these hosts to

```
upload a firmware onto the host
install the firmware
restart the host
reconnect to the host
verify the firmware version
```

On teardown, it closes all connections.

I'd like to add more tests, and properly modularize them into separate files, but I understand that I cannot define test-cases inside the init?

I'd like to be able to call test cases in the loop after where I update a firmware and restart the host.

Otherwise I have to duplicate the loop again, connecting to each host, then run the tests...

Is there a way to do what I want to do?
What is the proper way to do this?

I mean, once I have restarted a host and reconnected to it, I'd like to run multiple tests on it, that are sourced from other .robot files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Resource files, and user Keywords. Then you can have them used by the different Test Cases files.

The "tests" as you are thinking will have the validation logic, but the functional/setup part will be in your Keywords.